# Java SIP Plugin for Cordova or Phonegap for Audio and Video streaming

Tags: java, android, cordova, sip

I've been doing some research on Phonegap and Cordova, it seems there is no support for creating apps that have SIP and VOIP functionality since HTML5 and Javascript have little or no support for these protocols (webRTC and websockets are not yet supported on most mobile phone browsers). However I found out it is possible to create and use Plugins in order to use native functionality of the Operating Systems (iOS and Android in this case).

My question is that, if for example I write native JAVA codes for my Android-Phonegap application, will I be able to use it as a plugin to stream audio and video in my Android-Phonegap application? what are the limitations of using a plugin (with native functionality) in Phonegap or Cordova? Most of the plugin codes I checked online had a "Result" in the end, does this effect streaming of Audio and Video?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video.... I could potentially see a problem... BUT! HTML5 already has support for that so its OK. If looking to do SIP Video calls, look below.

You have HTML5 SIP clients that have been made: 
http://sipml5.org/

It is Open Source. I haven't used it, but I cannot imagine that the back-end of the codebase wouldn't be portable to mobile.

Emdedded SIP - I would take a good long look at the code used in LinPhone (http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html) and CSipSimple (https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) for your Java plugin Side ( You will need to build the required C libraries and use them as well ).

Now, PhoneGap provides a great Audio/Video Capture plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/blob/dev/doc/index.md

What you can do is integrate the Stream with some of the returns and tie-ins on the Media Capture plugin.

So, you have two options.

Answer (score 2):

A proof-of-concept Cordova app that uses SIP.js with the PhoneRTC plugin to make WebRTC calls over the internet.

https://github.com/joseph-onsip/sipjs-cordova

Comment: This is supposed to be for Android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a SIP plugin for Android devices. Hope it helps!

https://github.com/lglossman/SipManagerPlugin

Anything you need don't hesitate to contact me...